# Find index of an element in a vector given a pointer to that element

Tags: c++

I have a vector of structs, like so: `std::vector<mystruct> elems`.

If I then have a `mystruct` pointer, which I *know* is pointing to one of the elements of `elems`, how can I get its index within `elems`?

Comment: .. which begs the question, why are you refering to items in a `vector` using a pointer? There are no guarantees that the pointer will be the same after modifications to the vector...

Comment: @Nim Just reserve enough space to the vector and define a max Element count function for adding new elements. I thinks thats a pretty good method to save elements in (game)engines or thinks like that to get good caching behaviour. When using pointers, you don't know, where the element really is.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`ptr - &elems[0];`

As of C++03, vector storage is required to be contiguous, and the definition of "contiguous" in the standard is that `&v[n] == &v[0] + n;`

[Edit: from a fairly theoretical portability point of view, beware that implementations are permitted to define `SIZE_MAX` and `ptrdiff_t` such that it's possible to subtract two pointers within the same object with undefined result. You'd hope that no implementation will arrange for that to actually cause problems, but you never know. It's fairly easy for the implementation to avoid - just don't return allocations that big]

Comment: Ok, but shouldnt' I also divide by the struct size in this case ?

Comment: @Habalusa: no, don't divide by the struct size. Pointer arithmetic already takes into account the size of the static type referred to by the pointer.

Comment: @Habalusa: no, absolutely not, pointer arithmetic in C and C++ is in terms of the pointed-to data.

Comment: @Habalusa: No, because of the way pointer arithmetic works, i.e. ptr+1 is the address of pointer plus the size of what it points to.

Comment: @decltype: is that not equivalent to ptr - v.begin()? I guess I don't get why you dereference and then get the address.

Comment: @J. Frankenstein: `v.begin()` is an iterator, not (necessarily) a pointer. There's no guarantee that it is possible to subtract an iterator from a pointer, and a pointer is what the questioner started out with.

Answer (score 3):

Elements must be stored contiguously. Therefore:

```
mystruct * elem; // definitely within the vector
mystruct * first = &elems[0];
std::vector<mystruct>::size_type index = elem - first;
```

technically though should use `ptrdiff_t` rather than `size_type` to subtract pointers.

Comment: Hmm. I prefer `size_type`, since intuitively it can in principle hold all the possible values (up to `SIZE_MAX` if `sizeof(mystruct)` is 1). But I can't remember whether it's even valid to subtract two pointers that far apart. In practice either works, since most implementations won't give you an allocation that big to start with, and even if so there's a good chance of something sensible happening with wraparound pointer arithmetic.

Comment: @Steve: If the pointers `a` and `b` are so far apart that the result of `a-b` doesn't fit into a ptrdiff_t, `a-b` is undefined behaviour (5.7-6 from c++03). Storing the result in `size_type` won't hurt you though and it's not wrong in any way, but you also don't gain anything from it.

Comment: @etarion: The overflow occurs only if sizeof(struct)==1 and the vector is larger than half the available address space. I'd risk it. :-)

Comment: @Bo Persson: The point is that storing in size_type doesn't help you avoid ub, because it already happens at the subtraction part, not when storing, so storing in size_type or ptrdiff_t makes no difference - if one fails, the other does also.