# How to find the index of an element in a sorted vector given a pointer to that element

Tags: c++, vector

I have a vector `std::vector<MyClass> vec`. I'm trying to sort the vector and then find the index of an element given a pointer to it

```
sort(vec.begin(), vec.end(), ...);
auto index = myPointer - &vec[0];
```

I noticed that the value of `index` doesn't change when the vector is sorted and therefore is incorrect. Is there a way to directly get the correct index?

Comment: How is `myPointer` defined?

Comment: @dyukha It doesn't matter how it's defined. What matters is that after sorting, previously obtained addresses will not point to the same element anymore.

Comment: @duykha It's a pointer to instance of MyClass. My "solution" was taken from here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5179570/find-index-of-an-element-in-a-vector-given-a-pointer-to-that-element

Comment: From what I understand, you define `myPointer = ...` before sorting. After sorting the pointer still points to the same cell (hence the same index), however the content of that cell is different.

Comment: sorting a vector invalidates any pre-existing pointers to its elements (the pointers themselves don't change where they are pointing to, but the objects inside the vector may have moved around to new indexes). You need to update the pointer after sorting, such as using `std::find_if()` to find the wanted element again, and then dereference the returned iterator to access the element so you then can get its address.  But, given an iterator to an element, you can get its index using `std::distance()` instead.

Comment: Would it be sufficient to get the same information without sorting, by counting how many elements of the array are less than `*myPointer`?  (Of course, if there's a chance that multiple elements are equal to `*myPointer` then it would be difficult to predict where `std::sort` will put that exact element, though predicting where `std::stable_sort` would put it would be doable.)

Comment: After sorting, it would be necessary to reinitialise `myPointer`.   All `sort()` does is change the values of elements of the array.  It doesn't change the address of individual elements.

Answer (score 0):

Standard requires that `RandomIt` of sort meet the requirement of [ValueSwappable](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/ValueSwappable), which means it use `std::iter_swap` to swap elements during sorting. Your pointer address won't be changed, if it points to the 2nd element before sort, it will still point to the 2nd element after sort, but the 2nd element got changed after sort most of the time. You need to use `equal_range` to get a new pointer address after sorting.